# Are there lisp-like macros in the shell?

Tags: shell, macros, lisp

I have a set of shell commands that look like this

```
if check-some-condition $a then;
   do stuff
   run-exit-code $a
fi
```

where `check-some-condition` and `run-exit-code` could be replaced by functions taking a single argument $a, while `do stuff` is a placeholder for possibly several shell commands. Is it possible to emulate the Lisp functionality of a macro where I could just write

```
(my-macro $a stuff)
```

and have it replaced by the code above? I am using Bash but I can use any other shell if they have features that make this easier. I thought at first of using functions but I don't think I can pass in a block of commands.

Comment: No, the shell doesn't have a macro pre-processor. You can write a shell function that uses `eval`.

Comment: Can you use M4? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(computer_language)

Comment: @ptdecker I may use any tool. Would M4 be the canonical way of doing this?

Comment: M4 is a general-purpose macro processor. You'd probably need to pipe your entire script through it.

Comment: PowerShell has support for script blocks, but without knowing what `check-some-condition` and `run-exit-code` do, it's hard to say how easy those will be to convert to PowerShell (which is quite different from traditional unix shells).

Comment: @GuPe M4 is a pretty classic macro processor for unix so I would think it is pretty canonical

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a macro definition system in the shell, and consequently shell syntax is not walked in order to expand macros. However, the shell has a textual `eval` command. You can write a function which synthesizes shell syntax, such as by inserting arguments it has been given, into a template. The function can print that syntax, which the caller can capture using `$(...)` command substitution syntax and pass to `eval`:

```
eval $(macro-like foo bar)
```

The expansion will happen every time that line of code is executed.

I've done something like this on a very small number of occasions. I don't remember all the details, but I remember that the code was also taking advantage of Bash `local` variables, which have dynamic scope, like ancient Lisp dialects and `defvar` variables in Common Lisp.

In Bash, `eval` takes place in a dynamic environment which sees the surrounding `local` variables, which is something you can exploit; it can help bring about some macro-like semantics. In a Lisp with lexically scoped local variables, `eval`-ed code has no access to those variables, but macro-substituted code does.  Under dynamic scope, `evaled` code can access and assign surrounding locals.

Here is an example. Note that because `eval` is a command which has no control over expansions taking place in its argument space because it is called (analogously to `eval` in Lisp being a function which doesn't control argument evaluation), the client code is encumbered with quoting responsibilities.

```
# $1 = variable
# $2 = low
# $3 = high
# $4 = body
dofor()
{
   cat <<!
$1=$2 ;
while [ \$$1 -lt $3 ] ; do
  $4
  $1=\$(( $1 + 1 ))
done
!
}

eval "$(dofor i 0 100 'printf "[%d]\n" $i')"
```

We could make it so that

```
eval $(dofor i 0 100 'printf "[%d]\n" $i')
```

works without the quotes, at the cost of more heaps of arcane escapery inside `dofor`.

Imagine we extended the shell with a built-in command `evalcmd`, which let us write this instead of the above:

```
evalcmd dofor i 0 100 'printf "[%d]\n" $i'
```

Can we write that as a shell function? It turns out, yes:

```
# run the command specified in the arguments
# capturing its output, which is evaled in quotes
evcmd()
{
  eval "$("$@")"
}

evcmd dofor i 0 100 'printf "[%d]\n" $i'
```

Now, though still monstrously inefficient, it's substantially more ergonomic.

Finally, let's ask: could we split `dofor` into an a `dofor_impl` which generates the code, and a `dofor` command which calls `dofor_impl` and invokes the `evcmd` semantics? Also, yes:

```
dofor_impl()
{
   cat <<!
$1=$2 ;
while [ \$$1 -lt $3 ] ; do
  $4
  $1=\$(( $1 + 1 ))
done
!
}

dofor()
{
  # like evcmd, but inserting an operator into the left position
  eval "$(dofor_impl "$@")"
}

dofor i 0 100 'printf "[%d]\n" $i'
```

This is not bad for some simple uses, but what we can't achieve is not having to put the `$i` into a quote so that the substitution doesn't take place before `dofor` is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash you can define functions as follows:

```
function run_exit_code () {
    echo "EXIT $1"
}

function check_some_condition () {
    echo "CHECKING $1";
    true
}
```

And your code can execute commands associated with variables:

```
function my_code () {
    var=$1
    stuff=$2
    if check_some_condition $var; then
        echo "OK";
        $stuff;
        run_exit_code $var
    fi
}
```

So you can write, for example:

```
$ my_code /tmp 'ls /'
CHECKING /tmp
OK
bin  boot  cdrom  dev  etc  home  lib  lib32  lib64  libx32  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  swapfile  sys  tmp  usr  var
EXIT /tmp
```

If you want `stuff` to refer to `$var`, then you need to add `eval`:

```
function my_code () {
    var=$1
    stuff=$2
    if check_some_condition $var; then
        echo "OK";
        eval $stuff;                 # <<< eval
        run_exit_code $var
    fi
}
```

This allows you to write a quoted bash expression and have it beeing evaluated in the context of your function:

```
$ my_code / 'ls $var'
CHECKING /
OK
bin  boot  cdrom  dev  etc  home  lib  lib32  ...
EXIT /
```